# How to display following values in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

```
{"status":true,"data":[{"ref_id":"22","agent_id":"68","p_id":"84","description":"i am interested"},{"ref_id":"24","agent_id":"68","p_id":"84","description":"For more information about Bootstrap and Bootstrap Glyphicons, visit our Bootstrap Tutorial.For more information about Bootstrap and Bootstrap Glyphicons, visit our Bootstrap Tutorial"}
```

How to display the above DATA values using vue js?

Currently i use, but not working..

```
 <table>
 <tbody>
     <tr v-for="post in posts">
      <td>{{ post.p_id }}</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is this ajax response?

Comment: `{"status":true,"data":[{"ref_id":"22","agent_id":"68","p_id":"84","description":"i am interested"},{"ref_id":"24","agent_id":"68","p_id":"84","description":"For more information about Bootstrap and Bootstrap Glyphicons, visit our Bootstrap Tutorial.For more information about Bootstrap and Bootstrap Glyphicons, visit our Bootstrap Tutorial"} ` is this in your `data`?

Comment: How do you get this response and show your `Vue js` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your given data is not complete. If given data is `posts` response use `posts.data` instead just `posts`

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    posts:{"status":true,"data":[{"ref_id":"22","agent_id":"68","p_id":"84","description":"i am interested"},{"ref_id":"24","agent_id":"68","p_id":"84","description":"For more information about Bootstrap and Bootstrap Glyphicons, visit our Bootstrap Tutorial.For more information about Bootstrap and Bootstrap Glyphicons, visit our Bootstrap Tutorial"}]
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
 <table >
 <tbody>
    <tr v-for="post in posts.data">
      <th >Ref Id</th>
      <th >Agent Id</th>
      <th >PID</th>
     </tr>
     <tr v-for="post in posts.data">
      <td>{{ post.ref_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ post.agent_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ post.p_id }}</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```